# How to download file from url and manage download count in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `download.aspx` page. In `Page_Load` event i download file from url and Increase download count and store to database.

When i refresh page download count increased. if i deny to download count also increased.

I want to increase count when i save file from browser.

My code is as following

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:5045/Documents/sample.pdf";                        
            DownLoadFile(url);
            //This is code for download counter do entry in database
            SoftwareController.SoftwareDownloadHistoryEdit(0, Id, CommonController.GETMyIP(), false, "ADD");               
        }
    }

    protected void DownLoadFile(string URL)
    {
        System.Net.WebClient net = new System.Net.WebClient();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Expires = 0;
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;FileName=");
        Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/octet-stream";
        Response.BinaryWrite(net.DownloadData(URL));
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Denying or accepting to download a file is a local browser action. As far as the server is concerned the file is send once `DownLoadFile` completes. The server has no way of telling if the user clicked accept or deny.

Comment: I got you point but is there any way to force stopping duplicate downloads. because when i refresh page it will always count downloads